# Multiple NSTimers in application

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

I am performing some operation using `NSTimer` and running 3 `NSTimers` in main thread in **appDelegate**. Will it affect performance of application in terms of speed?

Comment: Just check it by using your app...and as far as UI is not blocking everything is fine.

Comment: i had created clock app using three timers for seconds,minutes and hour and my app was working fine.

Comment: Do you want to ask if 3 tasks with 3 various timers are worse than the same 3 tasks with the onest timer?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

The timers are very low overhead.  I don't think you'll see any effect at all.  If the frequencies are on the order of seconds, you can do what I did for an app that cared about several different time intervals:  One NSTimer firing each second, then modulo checks and notifications for whoever cared about each frequency.

```
- (void)secondsTimerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSInteger nowInterval = (NSInteger)[now timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SecondsTimerFired" object:self];

    if (nowInterval % 5 == 0) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Second_5_TimerFired" object:self];
    }

    if (nowInterval % 12 == 0) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Second_12_TimerFired" object:self];
    }
}
```

Another benefit was I had one place and one timer to invalidate and restart on app active/inactive events.